# Is it ok to test EJB3/JPA with standalone JPA?

Tags: java, testing, jpa, ejb-3.0

I have an JEE5 app using EJB3 with JPA. E.g I have some beans with

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I'd like to write some tests for those services. I know I can use embeddable container like OpenEJB, but as JPA is available in Java SE, I wonder if I can use it in testing?
Certainly I won't have all the

```
@PersistenceContext, @PersistenceUnit, @TransactionAttribute
```

features available. So my question is if this is worth trying (hand-made transaction management and so on)? Or should I go with embedded container? I'm talking about integration tests (with real, but in-memory database), not about mocking all stuff around.

**EDIT:**

One more thing as I'm quite new to testing in embedded container. Is it possible to inject e.g. Mockito's mock as an @EJB dependency to my bean under test? Or maybe it doesn't make sense in this setup?

Comment: Out of curiosity what would make you want to avoid testing in an EJB container?  Note all Java EE 6 compliant containers implement the EJB 3.1 Embedded EJB Container API, not just OpenEJB.

Comment: @David Blevins It is a bit complicated by the fact that he is stuck in JEE5, but yeah.

Comment: @David, nothing prevents me from that, except the fact I have JEE5 (but still can use OpenEJB I hope). I'm just wondering if testing EJB with JPA out of (any) container makes any sense if it originally lives in container and uses it's features like transactions, injections etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test a lot of things with Java SE / JPA. But there is a major part of what we call Integration Testing that will require massive amount of effort to mock up things, and some that just won't be doable without [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/)  or similar help. Do you want your EJB transactional functionality/etc to be included among the things you test? If so you have to implement tests that lives in a transactional environment as close to production as possible. I strongly suggest using a ejb-testing-framework.

Comment: So if you had to write EJB3 using JPA for some complex queries and transactions, would you go with embedded container or arquillian rather than standalone env?

Comment: Personally I would definitely go with Arquillian, but that is because I like to develop "inside" Arquillian, I basically grown accustomed almost dependant on developing my Enterprise Beans concurrently with writing "unit tests" for them in Arquillian. At the moment it takes 45-115 seconds to fully deploy our project to glassfish ("within" Netbeans/Eclipse), it takes 16-25ish seconds to execute a typical Arquillian test case (from "within" NetBeans/Eclipse). Some of the Arquillian test-cases survives and evolves into Integration Tests. This is JEE6/EJB 3.1 I'd do it for 3.0 as well.

Comment: If "all" I wanted to do was testing JPQL queries/etc, specific JPA stuff, I wouldn't use either - but that is not applicable as soon as we are interested in JTA transactions.

Comment: @grafthez And note, you can use OpenEJB with Arquillian if you want quicker test times.  I'd recommend the adapter for OpenEJB 3.  It has some Java EE 6 support but is still JPA 1.0, so there's no chance from a JPA perspective you'll accidentally go beyond JPA 1.0 and into JPA 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your service beans, I think a good approach is to use some mocking framework like EasyMock and mock the entity manager, so in that case you test just the piece of code you want to and not the entire thing.

You just need to add two constructors to your session bean, one default and one with the dependencies it needs so then you can provide mock objects there.

Hope it helps.